# Identities on $\cos n\theta$ and $\sin n\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that:

$$\cos{n\theta}=\cos^n{\theta}-
\binom {n} {2}\cos^{n-2} \theta \cdot \sin^2 \theta+
\binom {n} {4}\cos^{n-4} \theta \cdot \sin^{4} \theta -\cdots$$

$$\sin n\theta =
\binom {n} {1}\cos^{n-1} \theta \cdot \sin \theta -
\binom {n} {3}\cos^{n-3} \theta \cdot \sin^3\theta +\cdots$$

I don't see how to start.

Comment: hint: demoivre's theorem.

Comment: As @abel said: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

Comment: i was thinking in Leibtniz formula for diferential operator haha

Comment: Thanks, i know its demoivre', but i can´t prove them.

Comment: There is an elementary proof using induction and basic trig identities. Have you tried proving it, given that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, there are identities

$$\sin(α+β)=\sin(α)\cos(β)+\cos(α)\sin(β)$$
$$\sin(α–β)=\sin(α)\cos(β)–\cos(α)\sin(β)$$
$$\cos(α+β)=\cos(α)\cos(β)–\sin(α)\sin(β)$$
$$\cos(α–β)=\cos(α)\cos(β)+\sin(α)\sin(β)$$
with induction proof with Binomial theorem

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^{n-k}y^k = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^{k}y^{n-k}.$$

This is enough to prove the theorem. I managed to do it on a separate sheet.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? It works fine for integers, which is probably all the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

$\bullet \ \cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta) = e^{i \theta}$

$\bullet\ \ (e^{i\theta})^n = (\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n$

$\bullet \ \ (e^{i\theta})^n = e^{i(n\theta)} = \cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta) = (\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n $

> Now just use binomial theorem