# The behavior of $f(x,y) = r\cos(n\theta)$ for $n \geq 3$ odd, or $n$ even and $n = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis

I wonder whether one can write the function $f(x,y) = r\cos(n\theta)$ in the form of $x$ and $y$ for $n \geq 3$ odd, or $n$ even and $n = 1$. Of course the $r$ and $\theta$ are defined as $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y= r\sin(\theta)$.

*Background:* The original question asks some properties about the function
$$
f(x,y) = r\cos(3\theta) = \frac{x^3-3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}
$$
with $f(0,0) = (0,0)$. I showed that it is continuous, has every directional derivative at $(0,0)$, and the directional derivatives do not lie in a common plane. The question then asks to generalize the cases for all types of $n$.

Comment: FYI, a fairly closely related question to what you're asking, and what [KaviRamaMurthy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3654394/602049) below suggests, is [Identities on $\cos n\theta$ and $\sin n\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1255215/602049).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $f(x,y)=\Re (re^{in \theta})=\frac  1 {r^{n-1}} \Re (x+iy)^{n}$. Expand $(x+iy)^{n}$ by Binomial Theorem.